# Rails 3.1 application can't deploy on Heroku. Getting at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" without any identifiable indication of why

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have been tasked with upgrading an old and robust Rails 2.3.1 application to Rails 3.1.  Everything has gone fairly "not" so smooth until slamming into an invisible yet notorious brick wall called "deploying something working perfectly locally but when on heroku, not so much."

Basically after deploying my branch to heroku like:

```
git push heroku mitchell_troubleshoot_some_issues:master
```

I get an error page with "not" a whole lot of useful information in the logs from what I can tell, though I have included them below.

```
2014-03-10T23:50:13.187273+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `reverse_each'
2014-03-10T23:50:13.187939+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2014-03-10T23:50:13.187273+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/plugins/seed/lib/calendar_date_select.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
2014-03-10T23:50:13.187939+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
2014-03-10T23:50:13.187939+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/plugin.rb:80:in `eval'
2014-03-10T23:50:13.187939+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:92:in `initialize!'
2014-03-10T23:50:13.188396+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2014-03-10T23:50:13.187481+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
2014-03-10T23:50:13.188113+00:00 app[web.1]:      from config.ru:4:in `require'
2014-03-10T23:50:13.188113+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2014-03-10T23:50:13.188396+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `eval'
2014-03-10T23:50:13.188568+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
2014-03-10T23:50:13.187939+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.
9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
2014-03-10T23:50:13.188396+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:760:in `call'
2014-03-10T23:50:13.188396+00:00 app[web.1]:      from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2014-03-10T23:50:13.188396+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:760:in `build_app!'
2014-03-10T23:50:13.188396+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `block in builder'
2014-03-10T23:50:13.188568+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:137:in `start'
2014-03-10T23:50:14.822134+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-03-10T23:50:14.841895+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-03-10T23:50:14.843444+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-03-10T23:50:20.148711+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn_rails -p 21066 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2014-03-10T23:50:21.875912+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-03-10T23:50:21.875542 #2]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
2014-03-10T23:50:28.553086+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][03/10/14 23:50:28 +0000 66936d53-7909-4126-bf20-bd00654ebc56 (2)] INFO : Starting the New Relic Agent.
2014-03-10T23:50:28.558214+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][03/10/14 23:50:28 +0000 66936d53-7909-4126-bf20-bd00654ebc56 (2)] INFO : Environment: staging
2014-03-10T23:50:28.558214+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][03/10/14 23:50:28 +0000 66936d53-7909-4126-bf20-bd00654ebc56 (2)] INFO : Dispatcher: unicorn
2014-03-10T23:50:28.558455+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][03/10/14 23:50:28 +0000 66936d53-7909-4126-bf20-bd00654ebc56 (2)] INFO : Application: conference-2014-staging
2014-03-10T23:50:28.558455+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][03/10/14 23:50:28 +0000 66936d53-7909-4126-bf20-bd00654ebc56 (2)] INFO : Connecting workers after forking.
2014-03-10T23:50:28.642624+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][03/10/14 23:50:28 +0000 66936d53-7909-4126-bf20-bd00654ebc56 (2)] INFO : Installing DelayedJob instrumentation hooks
2014-03-10T23:50:28.642624+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][03/10/14 23:50:28 +0000 66936d53-7909-4126-bf20-bd00654ebc56 (2)] INFO : Installing Net instrumentation
2014-03-10T23:50:28.642807+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][03/10/14 23:50:28 +0000 66936d53-7909-4126-bf20-bd00654ebc56 (2)] INFO : Installing DelayedJob instrumentation
2014-03-10T23:50:28.643980+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][03/10/14 23:50:28 +0000 66936d53-7909-4126-bf20-bd00654ebc56 (2)] INFO : Installing Unicorn instrumentation
2014-03-10T23:50:28.643980+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][03/10/14 23:50:28 +0000 66936d53-7909-4126-bf20-bd00654ebc56 (2)] INFO : Detected Unicorn, please see additional documentation: https://newrelic.com/docs/troubleshooting/im-using-unicorn-and-i-dont-see-any-data
2014-03-10T23:50:28.644305+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][03/10/14 23:50:28 +0000 66936d53-7909-4126-bf20-bd00654ebc56 (2)] INFO : Installing ActiveRecord instrumentation
2014-03-10T23:50:28.644473+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][03/10/14 23:50:28 +0000 66936d53-7909-4126-bf20-bd00654ebc56 (2)] INFO : Installing Rails 3 Controller instrumentation
2014-03-10T23:50:28.644653+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][03/10/14 23:50:28 +0000 66936d53-7909-4126-bf20-bd00654ebc56 (2)] INFO : Installing Rails 3.1/3.2 view instrumentation
2014-03-10T23:50:28.691067+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][03/10/14 23:50:28 +0000 66936d53-7909-4126-bf20-bd00654ebc56 (2)] INFO : Installing Rails3 Error instrumentation
2014-03-10T23:50:28.691067+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][03/10/14 23:50:28 +0000 66936d53-7909-4126-bf20-bd00654ebc56 (2)] INFO : Finished instrumentation
2014-03-10T23:50:28.691663+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][03/10/14 23:50:28 +0000 66936d53-7909-4126-bf20-bd00654ebc56 (2)] INFO : NewRelic::Agent::Samplers::DelayedJobSampler sampler not available: No DJ worker present
2014-03-10T23:50:28.837595+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir': Read-only file system - /public (Errno::EROFS)
2014-03-10T23:50:28.837595+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:221:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.837595+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `block in mkdir_p'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.837595+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `reverse_each'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.837818+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/plugin.rb:80:in `eval'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.837818+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/plugin.rb:80:in `block in <class:Plugin>'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.837595+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `fu_mkdir'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.837595+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/plugins/seed/lib/calendar_date_select.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.837595+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `each'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.837595+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `mkdir_p'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.837818+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.837595+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/plugins/seed/lib/calendar_date_select.rb:26:in `each'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.837818+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.837818+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.837595+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/plugins/seed/lib/calendar_date_select.rb:29:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.838039+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.838039+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.837818+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/plugins/seed/init.rb:1:in `block in <class:Plugin>'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.837818+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.837818+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.838039+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.837818+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.838796+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `block in builder'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.838796+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `eval'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.838796+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/bin/unicorn_rails:139:in `call'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.838796+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/bin/unicorn_rails:139:in `block in rails_builder'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.837818+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.838039+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.838039+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.838796+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:760:in `build_app!'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.838796+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:137:in `start'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.838796+00:00 app[web.1]:      from config.ru:1:in `new'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.839018+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `load'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.838796+00:00 app[web.1]:      from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.838039+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:92:in `initialize!'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.838039+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.838039+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/config/environment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.838039+00:00 app[web.1]:      from config.ru:4:in `require'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.838796+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:760:in `call'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.839018+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `<main>'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.839018+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.838039+00:00 app[web.1]:      from config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2014-03-10T23:50:28.838796+00:00 app[web.1]:      from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2014-03-10T23:50:30.102462+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-03-10T23:50:30.096124+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-03-10T23:50:30.960170+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=stagingconference2014.myappprogram.org request_id=89e5fc26-287d-4aac-acba-ee9015668556 fwd="75.146.48.253" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-03-10T23:50:52.092445+00:00 heroku[api]: Rollback to v44 by info@mycompany.com
2014-03-10T23:50:52.092543+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v64 created by info@mycompany.com
```

Here is my gemfile.  It is an assortment of updated gems from the Rails 2.3.1 version and some new dependencies in accordance with the later version.  I have also made some adjustments in accordance with some of the suggestions I found here on overflow.

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby "1.9.3"
gem "rails", "3.1.0", :require => nil
#gem "sqlite3-ruby", :require => "sqlite3"
gem 'pg'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'rack-timeout', '0.0.4'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'paperclip' , '~> 2.8.0'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0' #, :lib => 'will_paginate', :source => 'http://gems.github.com'
gem 'RedCloth', '~> 4.2.9'
gem "ckeditor"

# bundler requires these gems in all environments
# gem "nokogiri", "1.4.2"
# gem "geokit"



gem 'newrelic_rpm', '~> 3.5.5.38'
gem 'rename'
gem "exception_notification"
gem 'databasedotcom', '~> 1.3.2'
gem 'databasedotcom-rails' #, :git => 'git://github.com/jtalis/databasedotcom-rails.git', :branch => 'master'
gem 'authlogic', "~> 3.1.0"
gem 'acts_as_list'
gem 'acts_as_indexed'
gem 'acts_as_tree_rails3'
gem 'rails3-restful-authentication', '~> 3.0.1'
gem 'acts_as_taggable_on', '~> 3.0.0.rc1'
gem 'prototype-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'calendar_date_select', '~> 2.0.0'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '3.1.0'
gem 'flying-sphinx'
gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem "jquery-rails"
gem 'pothoven-attachment_fu'

#group :assets do
  #gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
#end
group :production, :staging do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
group :development do
  # bundler requires these gems in development
  # gem "rails-footnotes"
end

group :test do
  # bundler requires these gems while running tests
  # gem "rspec"
  # gem "faker"
end
```

Here is my staging.rb. At this point it looks exactly like my development.rb

```
MyAppconference::Application.configure do
    # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

    # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
    # every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
    # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
    config.cache_classes = false
    config.cache_store = :file_store, "tmp/cache"

    # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
    config.whiny_nils = true

    # Show full error reports and disable caching
    config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    ######
    config.log_level = :debug
    #config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store, {:namespace => 'seed'}
    config.cache_store = :file_store, "tmp/cache"

    # Don't care if the mailer can't send
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
    config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

    # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
    # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

    # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
    config.active_support.deprecation = :log

    # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
    config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

    # Do not compress assets
    config.assets.compress = false

    # Expands the lines which load the assets
    config.assets.debug = true

    config.serve_static_assets = true
    #config.assets.enabled = false
    config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/public/"
    config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/public/javascripts"
    #config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/public/javascripts/ckeditor"
    config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/public/stylesheets"
    config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/public/images"
end
```

I have tried running:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate --app conference-2014-staging
```

And I get the following results:

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.4962
rake aborted!
Read-only file system - /public
/app/vendor/plugins/seed/lib/calendar_date_select.rb:29:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/plugins/seed/lib/calendar_date_select.rb:26:in `each'
/app/vendor/plugins/seed/lib/calendar_date_select.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/app/vendor/plugins/seed/init.rb:1:in `block in <class:Plugin>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/plugin.rb:80:in `eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/plugin.rb:80:in `block in <class:Plugin>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:92:in `initialize!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/app/config/environment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:78:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Can anyone help?  I would very much appreciate it.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like the `calendar_date_select` plugin is loaded from `vendor/plugins/seed` directory. Hard to tell what version it is from here, but it looks like the plugin is trying to manage assets in your public directory. More info from this commit: https://github.com/timcharper/calendar_date_select/commit/e3e515036507112c1dc8c7a250f2782b57870ad8. Have you tried removing that dependency and falling back to the one specified in your Gemfile?

Comment: Thanks for the tidbit.  Ill check it out and circle back around.

Comment: Yeah - that plugin is trying to create a directory.  Very weird.